# How can I get Drupal module name programmatically?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'm working on my own module. I realize I constantly need to manually type my module name in different places. Most popular usage is with [`drupal_get_path($type, $name)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7) function (I have more then 10 of these in my code). Where `$name` is theme or module name. During that time I need to already change my module name 3 times. As you can surmise I also need change all module names hard-coded in my project. So I thought it would be nice to have some convenient function to grab this name automatically.

How can I get machine module name programmatically?

For example if you have your module in following directory..

```
sites/all/modules/my_module/
```

..then you can grab it in this way

```
drupal_get_current_module_name(); // return my_module
```

Comment: you can always get the module.info file parse it as an .ini file and get the name

Comment: Can you give an example of a use case?  just wondering why you would need to programmatically find the module name of the module that you're writing code for.  Or is the code getting the module name supposed to be in a different module?

Comment: If I want to have module name with very long name and i want to create [description] theme then (as far as I know) I should chreate something like 'uc_very_long_name_description' (namespace). Then I need about 10 more theme functions. What I want to do is create my helper theme function (_theme()) and in side it use module name. And in case of changing module name, I don't need to change all these theme function names + all theme() call ups. Also this call ups looks much more human then original ones.. 
`_theme('description')` instead of
`theme('uc_very_long_name_description')` etc.

Comment: I've just update question with background of my question.

Comment: @Phoenix can you please give some code example, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you should know by convention - if you have: `sites/all/modules/my_module/` then the machine name of the module should match the folder name - `my_module`.

Virtually all contributed modules follow this convention, and you should too.

It is possible to have your .info and .module file not match the name of the folder, but this isn't correct.

If you are already executing code inside your module, you should already know the machine name of the module by virtue of the name of the file you're editing - unless you're trying to do something that I'm not understanding.

Edit: Since we've determined you're just trying to call your module's theme function, you don't actually need to know the name.

If you have:

```
/** Implements theme_table **/
function my_really_long_module_name_table() {}
```

Your function might get called like this:

```
theme('table');
```

There is a little more to it than that, but the theme engine will make a determination about which theme functions get called based on what is implementing them.

It sounds like you may want to read up on some of the basics of the Drupal theme system.
Here's a good start for learning the Drupal 6 theme layer: http://drupal.org/node/165706

Comment: Hi, yes I know the name of module but I want it make proof in case of changing module (then also file(s)) name..

Comment: I think you may have some general confusion about how Drupal modules are used, or maybe you're trying to accomplish something else in a round about way.  Can you explain why you think you need the current module name, and what you're trying to do with it?

Comment: I have theme function to use with really long name. And also I want to use the module name in the beginning of theme function to make it as some kind of namespace. But my module name is really long so I want to get this name from function. If this make sense?

Comment: In the typical usage of the Drupal theme system, you don't need to know the module name, the theme engine will figure that out based on which modules or themes are implementing that theme hook.

I will edit original answer to help explain.

Comment: Hi, yes I know how this works i've explaind what I need it for in comment above [comment14476483_11053461](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053461/how-get-drupal-module-name#comment14476483_11053461)

Answer (score 1):

I figure out something like this:

```
function get_current_module_name() {
    return array_shift(explode('.', end(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, __FILE__))));
}
```

but don't know is't the best way to do it..

UPDATE:
I see now it's better to use basename

```
$name = basename(__FILE__, '.module');
```

UPDATE 2:
I think if this is needed across whole module  then it could be accessible via constant defined in the very beginning of the module e.g.:

```
define('MODULE_NAME', basename(__FILE__, '.module'));
```

Then you could use all the time in all your function like this:

```
drupal_get_path('module', MODULE_NAME);
```